# Converse statements for convolutions of probability distributions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

There is a [list of convolutions of probability distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_convolutions_of_probability_distributions) on wikipedia. Using that list we can find convolution distribution of given independent random variables.

From [this online tutorial](https://www.statlect.com/probability-distributions/binomial-distribution#hid3) I found that the converse statement is true for the binomial distribution, i.e. if $Y \sim \mathrm{Bin}(n,p)$ then there exist i.i.d $X_1, \ldots ,X_n \sim \mathrm{Bern}(p)$ such that $\displaystyle Y = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$.

**So, are there similar converse statements for other convolutions from the above-mentioned list (excluding the last one)?**

For example consider r.v. $Y \sim \mathrm{Pois}(\lambda), \, \lambda \gt 0$. Can we claim that there exist independent random variables $X_1 \sim \mathrm{Pois}(\lambda_1), X_2 \sim \mathrm{Pois}(\lambda_2), X_3 \sim \mathrm{Pois}(\lambda_3)$ such that $\lambda_1 + \lambda_2 + \lambda_3 = \lambda$ and $Y = X_1 + X_2 + X_3$?

I know that there is a [list of infinitely divisible distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Infinitely_divisible_probability_distributions). 
And some distributions present in both above-mentioned lists. Unfortunately, the property of infinite divisibility doesn't indicate distribution law of the summands (it only says that the summands exist and they are i.i.d).

Comment: Yes for your last question. Sum of independent random variables with Poisson distribution  is poisson distributed with parameter the sum of the parameters.

Comment: @Shashi, It is better to formulate this way: if the finite sum of independent non-negative random variables has a Poisson distribution, then the summands themselves must have the Poisson distribution. That is so called [Raikov's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raikov%27s_theorem).

Comment: Well, there is a similar [Cramer's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%27s_theorem) for the normal distribution: if the finite sum of independent random variables has a normal distribution, then the summands themselves must have the normal distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slight tangent, but perhaps an angle you may find interesting is to look into Infinitely Divisible distributions.

A probably distribution $X$ is said to be infinititely divisible if for any $N \geq 1$ there exists a collection $(Y_n)_{n = 1}^N$ of independent identically distributed random variables such that:

$$ X = \sum_{n = 1}^N Y_n,$$

where the equality stands for equality in distribution.

As an example, from the fact that $\text{Poi}(\lambda) + \text{Poi}(\mu) = \text{Poi}(\mu + \lambda)$, from the comments above, then we can see that in fact for any fixed $N \geq 1$, and $\lambda > 0$:

$$ \text{Poi}(\lambda) = \sum_{n=1}^N \text{Poi}\left( \frac{\lambda}{N} \right),$$

so that Poisson variables are infinitely divisible. Similar proofs work Normal distributions, as well as Gamma distributions.

A simple example of a non-infinitely divisible distribution would be the Bernoulli distribution (see proof below). Similarly the Uniform distribution is not infinitely divisible.

**Bernoulli is not Infinitely Divisible**
Consider the case of the Bernoulli distribution, $X$, with $P(X = 1) = p$, with $0 < p < 1$ (the cases $p = 0,1$ are trivially infinitely divisible).

Fix $N = 2$, then if $X$ were infinitely divisible there would exists $Y_1, \,Y_2$ independent and identically distributed such that

$$X = Y_1 + Y_2$$

Since $X \in \{0,1\}$ the i.i.d. assumption forces $Y_n \in \left\{0, \frac12\right\}$.

But then the support of $Y_1 + Y_2$ is $\{0,\frac12, 1\}$; since $p \neq 0,1$ we have

$$P\left(Y_1+Y_2 = \frac12\right) > 0$$

whereas $P(X = \frac12) = 0$, so we have a contradiction.

Comment: Just one question. If we use infinite divisibility of Poisson distribution to decompose the Poisson r.v. into the sum of i.i.d. r.vs and then want to apply [Raikov's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raikov%27s_theorem) we need to ensure that all the identically distributed summands are non-negative (according to Wikipedia). The last thing does not follow directly from the definition of infinite divisible distribution. Can we just say that the non-negativity of the summands follows from their identical distribution and the non-negativity of the their sum?

Comment: I'm using a weaker result than Raikov's theorem, which is a standard textbook exercise. Fairly easy computation (eg. manipulating the formulae for the distribution functions) using Poisson variables should convince you that of the fact I state above: $\text{Poi}(\lambda) + \text{Poi}(\mu) = \text{Poi}(\lambda + \mu)$. This is weaker than Raikov, but sufficient to prove infinite divisibility of a Poisson distribution (using Poisson rate $\lambda/N$).

Comment: Ok, now I understand your idea. Unfortunately, this way doesn't show the uniqueness of the Poisson distribution for the summands in the property of the infinite divisibility. Nevertheless, you have a simple and good result.